# Working with react-pdf/renderer and need to wait for the data to populate before download

Tags: reactjs, pdf, react-pdf

I have a download pdf button that when clicked will populate the pdf with `onStartPDFGeneration` but in order to download the PDF, I need to wrap that button with `PDFDownloadLink` from `react-pdf/renderer`.

The first time I click the link, nothing happened because the data is getting processed. If I press it again the pdf will generate with that data and download.

How can I get the `PDFDownloadLink` to wait for all the data to populate

```
<PDFDownloadLink document={<MyDocument />} fileName="example.pdf">
  <Button
    onClick={onStartPDFGeneration}
  />
</PDFDownloadLink>
```

`pdfState.data` is coming from redux
`qrCodeArray` is in local state with `useState`

```
  const MyDocument = () => {
    return (
      <>
        {pdfState.data && (
          <Document>
            <Page size="A4" style={styles.page}>
              <View style={styles.headerSection}>
                <Text>test</Text>
              </View>
              <View>
                <Image style={{ width: "40%" }} src={qrCodeArray[0]} />
              </View>
            </Page>
          </Document>
        )}
      </>
    );
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is disable the button when the promise is in pending state  or data is not available.

```js
<PDFDownloadLink document={<MyDocument />} fileName="example.pdf">
  <Button
    onClick={onStartPDFGeneration}
    disabled={!pdfState.data}
  />
</PDFDownloadLink>
```